# Angular 6 Parent/Children Routing and Shared Data

Tags: html, angular, routes, nested, children

I'm having a problem with nested children-parents routing and shared data.
My project contains 4 components: Course-List, Course-Detail, Course-Play, Course Quiz, and the scheme is like that [**(Click Here)**](https://image.ibb.co/nKCiqe/Screen_Shot_2018_08_06_at_16_58_57.png).
The data is pass like that: every course have array of segment and every segments have array of questions. All the data I get from a backend and it pass correctly.

I have a problem with course-quiz and routing between course-play and course-quiz. this is what I want:

1. After I click on a link to start the quiz in course-play, that the course-quiz will open in a designated div and from there start it's life. Also that the route'll change as well
2. I want that every time only one question will show, and with a next link it'll go to the next one

I did make the div to change to what's in the child, but the route didn't change and also the data from the parents didn't pass and I don't know how to make it pass in the way I wrote in 2.

I didn't add course-list, course-detail and course-service because everything is fine there and not related to this problem. This is all the relevant code:

**course.ts**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  autor: string;
  segments: ISegment[];
}

export interface ISegment {
  id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_title: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  data: string;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}

export interface IQuestion {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  answer1: string;
  answer2: string;
  answer3: string;
  answer4: string;
  correct: number;
}
```

**app-routing**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CourseListComponent } from './courses/course-list/course-list.component';
import { CourseDetailComponent } from './courses/course-detail/course-detail.component';
import { CoursePlayComponent } from './courses/course-play/course-play.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CourseQuizComponent } from './courses/course-play/course-quiz/course-quiz.component';


// Routing array - set routes to each html page
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id/segments/:id', component: CoursePlayComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [{ path: 'questions/:id', component: CourseQuizComponent }]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {  }
```

**course-play.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { ISegment } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';


// Couse-play decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-play-course-play',
  templateUrl: './course-play.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-play.component.sass']
})

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  course: ICourse;
  courseId: number;
  public currentSegment: ISegment;
  public showChildren: boolean;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { this.showChildren = false; }


    ngOnInit() {
        // save this course id from course-detail and get http request from the service
        this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"))
        this.getCourse(this.courseId);
      }

      // Get course detail by id
      getCourse(id: number) {
        this.courseService.getCourse(this.courseId).subscribe(
          course => {
              this.course = course;

              // get the current segment id to use it on the html file
              const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
              this.getCurrentSegment(id);
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        }

      // search in course single segment by id and save it in currentSegment
      // to use it in the html file
      getCurrentSegment(id: number){
          this.currentSegment = this.course.segments.find(d => d.id === id);
      }

      changeShowChildren() {
        this.showChildren = !this.showChildren;
      }
}
```

**course-play.html**

```js
  <div class="row content" *ngIf="course">
    <!-- Side nav-bar -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <!-- Image Logo -->
      <div id="head_sidebar">
        <img src="./assets/images/lg-white.png" class="d-inline-block align-top logo" alt="" routerLink="/courses" style="outline: none">
        <h3>{{course.title}}</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 sidenav">
        <!-- Menu elemets -->
        <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" *ngFor="let unit of course.segments | groupBy: 'unit_title'; let i = index">
          <h6 class="course_play_title">Unit {{ i+1 }}: {{ unit.key }} </h6>
          <ul>
            <li class="course_play_item"  *ngFor="let lesson of unit.value">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/courses', course.id, 'segments', lesson.id]" (click)=getCurrentSegment(lesson.id)>{{lesson.name}} </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="col-md-9 no-gutters" *ngIf="currentSegment">
      <!-- Video Div -->
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Video'">
        <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
        <p class="small-text" *ngIf="course.segments?.length > 0">lesson {{currentSegment.id}} of {{course.segments?.length}}</p>
        <hr>
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" [src]='currentSegment.data | safe'></iframe>
      </div>

      <!-- Quiz Div -->
      <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="currentSegment.segment_type === 'Quiz'">
        <div class="col-md-12 course_play_body text-center" *ngIf="showChildren === false">
          <h1>{{currentSegment.name}}</h1>
          <p class="text-left"> Now that you've finished this unit, It's time to take a short quiz and see what you learned so far!
              You'll need to choose one out of four answers which you think is correct.
              After you've finished the quiz, you'll get your grade. feel free to re-take this quiz as much as you like.
              Good Luck!
            </p>
            <p class="big-text" *ngIf="currentSegment.questions?.lenght > 0"> {{currentSegment.questions?.lenght}} questions </p>
            <a (click) = "showChildren = true"><h4>Start Quiz</h4></a>
          </div>
            <quiz-course *ngIf="showChildren === true" [questions]="currentSegment?.questions"></quiz-course>
        </div>

  </div>
```

**course-quiz.component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

import { ICourse } from '../../course';
import { ISegment } from '../../course';
import { IQuestion } from '../../course';
import { CourseService } from '../../course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'quiz-course',
  templateUrl: './course-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-quiz.component.sass']
})

export class CourseQuizComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() questions: IQuestion[];

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**course-quiz.html**

```js
<ul *ngFor="let item of questions">
  <li>{{questions.question}}</li>
  <li>{{questions.answer1}</li>
  <li>{{questions.answer2}}</li>
  <li>{{questions.answer3}}</li>
  <li>{{questions.answer4}}</li>
</ul>

<a>Next Question</a>
```